# Codelite sidebar is gone

Tags: codelite

I'm new to CodeLite. I clicked something that hid the sidebar navigation.

When I go to View > Show Menu Bar, the option is grayed out.

Apologies for the simple question. I'm new to this IDE.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am working in a Linux-based system, but I think I still might be able to help. I am also new to codelite/c++ and I ran into this same issue.
Go to view>workspace pane or press ctrl+alt+W
HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Alt+W...that's all you need (Eureka!)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).